# How to trim a clip affected by speed control?

Tags: video

Newbie here.

I've imported a .mp4 video I recorded, but the video and the sound is split into two channels and the video clip is way longer than the sound. After some googling I found that I can use the Speed Control effect strip to modify the length of the video to match the sound channel.

However, when I do this and then attempt to split up the video, everything just goes bananas. The speed control will make the left side of the split play the entire video at a much higher speed, while the right side of the split will be completely desynced from the audio.

It doesn't make sense to me, so I need some help figuring this out.
If possible I'd like to permanently change the speed of the video, or preferably combine the video and the sound channels into one channel so that I can cut and mix and match without risking it going out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

There are some parameters to check for having audio and video in sync, many others softwares set them automatically, Blender doesn't, so you have to configure them manually.

First of all in the timeline set the sync type to AV Sync (this affects the behaviour during live playback only, it doesn't affect the renders).

Then load the movie in the movie clip editor, read its FPS value and set the same amount in the dimensions properties tab.

Lastly be aware that audio also has to match its sample rate: most commons are 44100 and 48000 (but this is automatically set).

When your audio and video will be in sync you can use the speed control effect strip to manipulate the video as you expect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a quick and informative answer! Setting the FPS of the project to 30 fixed the desyncing without having to use Speed Control.